# Clojure, comparing vectors of integers: why "longer" vector is always "greater"? Is there a remedy?

Tags: vector, clojure, comparator

It works like this:

```
pcc.core=> (compare [4] [2 2])
-1
pcc.core=> (compare [4 0] [2 2])
1
```

I want a vector comparator with "string semantics":

```
pcc.core=> (compare-like-strings [4] [2 2])
1 ;; or 2, for that matter
pcc.core=> (compare-like-strings [4 0] [2 2])
1
```

Is there a lightweigt, nice way to get what I want?

Comment: Why is this "string semantics"? I would expect a string comparison to have the same behavior as vector (that's how Clojure and Java behave at least).

Comment: @AlexMiller, `(compare "abc" "ac")` => -1, but `(compare [1 2 3] [1 3])` => 1.

Comment: @AlexMiller Strings are traditionally compared lexicographically, and both Clojure and Java carry on this tradition. The difference is that vectors compare length before contents, whereas strings only use length if the first N items all compare the same.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
(defn compare-like-strings [a b]
  (let [res (first (drop-while zero? (map compare a b)))]
    (if (nil? res)
      0
      res)))
```

The idea would be to do a pairwise comparison, returning a seq of -1, 0, or 1s and then drop all leading 0s. The first non-zero element is the first element that differs.

Comment: Don't forget the case where all elements are identical - it should produce 0.

Comment: Additionally, what if we compare `[1 1 2 2]` and `[1 1]`?

Comment: Right, just noticed that and fixed the case where both are equal. I guess the `[1 1 2 2]` vs `[1 1]` case depends on your requirements? Alexey's call I guess. Nice code golf though, improvements in length are welcome :).

Comment: [1 1] should be lesser than [1 1 2 2]

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
(defn compare-like-strings [[x & xs] [y & ys]]
  (let [c (compare x y)]
    (if (and (zero? c) (or xs ys))
      (recur xs ys)
      c)))
```

Comment: This misses a number of edge cases, via the nil-punning on `xs` and `ys` and the failure to check for empty inputs. For example, `(compare-like-strings [nil] [])` returns 0.

Comment: @amalloy good catch. Probably best to compare them with a plain old loop. If you run out of one and it's been matching so far, return -1 or 1 depending on which one ran out.

Comment: My rule of thumb is basically to never use `[x & xs]` destructuring. It's appealing in theory, but in practice I always want to be lazier, or can't be sure that there's at least one element, or something like that, so I end up using `seq`, `first`, and `next` or `rest`.

Comment: I ended up fixing it with `count` and `subvec` but the code is too ugly to post. Good point about `[x & xs]`, in this case it's compounded because there are two sequences.

Comment: I agree that comparing in a loop is best: the least creative and most tedious solution beats all the clever HOF stuff when you're dealing with two sequences of different length. If you're careful, you can make it work for arbitrary seqs as well as vectors.

Answer (score 2):

So far it's

```
(defn cmpv-int
  "Compare vectors of integers using 'string semantics'"
  [vx vy]
  (let [res (first (drop-while zero? (map compare vx vy)))
        diffenence (- (count vx) (count vy))]
     (if res res diffenence)
    )
  )
```

based on Fabian approach.

Comment: This is the only answer here (besides mine, now) which actually gets all the cases right. A few notes about style, though: Lisps don't like close-parens on their own line, so just take those last two and pile them up right at the end, like `difference)))`. Also, `(if x x y)` is a long-winded way of writing `(or x y)`; once you've done that, you can inline all the locals, to get `(or (first ...) (- ...))`.

Comment: If you incorporate @amalloy's proposed changes I think no one would complain if you accepted your own answer. It solves your problem and does so quite cleanly and elegantly.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `subvec`?

```
(defn compare-like-strings
  [vec1 vec2]
  (let [len (min (count vec1) (count vec2))]
    (compare (subvec vec1 0 len)
             (subvec vec2 0 len))))
```

Comment: Doesn't actually work when one vector is a prefix of the other: this is just a long-winded way of writing Fabian's answer, `(-> (first (remove zero? (map compare xs ys))) (or 0))`

Answer (score 0):

Comparison seems to work if both vectors are the same length, so let me offer this:

```
(defn compare-vectors
  [a b]
  (compare
    (reduce conj a (map #{} b))
    (reduce conj b (map #{} a))))
```

This is basically padding the inputs with as many `nil`s as necessary before running the comparison. I like how it looks (and it should fit your requirements perfectly) but I'm not particularly sure I'd recommend it to anyone. ;)

```
(compare-vectors [2 2] [2 2]) ;; => 0
(compare-vectors [4 2] [2 2]) ;; => 1
(compare-vectors [2 2] [4 2]) ;; => -1
(compare-vectors [4]   [2 2]) ;; => 1
```

**EDIT:** I probably wouldn't - it's terribly inefficient.

Comment: This answer also doesn't work for vectors which contain nils: consider `[]` and `[nil]`.

Comment: @amalloy: oh, I know. but since everyone here was basically writing the same loop (and the problem was not well-defined enough to have an exact solution), I just wanted to tackle it from a different perspective.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments on Diego's answer, I think the least creative approach is best here: just write a loop, enumerate all the cases, and slog through it. As a bonus, this approach also works for arbitrary sequences, possibly lazy, because we don't need to rely on any vector-specific tricks.

```
(defn lexicographic-compare
  ([xs ys]
     (lexicographic-compare compare xs ys))
  ([compare xs ys]
     (loop [xs (seq xs) ys (seq ys)]
       (if xs
         (if ys
           (let [c (compare (first xs) (first ys))]
             (if (not (zero? c))
               c
               (recur (next xs), (next ys))))
           1)
         (if ys
           -1
           0)))))
```